# Найти лишние файлы javascript

Tags: jquery, prototype, javascript

Сайт делался очень давно, потом его переделывали, сначала все работало на prototype, потом часть переписали на jQuery, но prototype все же остался, ибо некоторые сервисы было в лом переписывать из-за их объемности. Сейчас 2 фремворка совместно работают.

Также на сайте куча разных примочек, ну там для листающихся слайдеров и т.д.

Код настолько загадили что в главный файл уже жутко заходить, естественно уже никто не помнит для чего какой скрипт, изначально все валилось на главную страницу и почти весь js грузится на главную и на все остальные.

Как сейчас понять какие js файлы уже не нужны, которые не используются, чтобы без вреда для сайта, ибо возможно что файл используется на какой-то одной странице, но он подгружается в каждую. Это ужасно, и хотелось бы навести порядок + повысить качество шаблона html + ускорить страницу.

Comment: @trec я когда-то отвечал на подобный вопрос, попробуйте поюзать поиск, к сожалению я быстро найти не смог ( да, такой камушек в огород не паливный :) )

Answer (score 1):

Переписывать или пересматривать странички, одну за другой, потихоньку отмечаяя нужные функции и переписывая их в нормальный код. А дальше методом исключения, то что осталось можно сносить. Как вариант, а копать в самом коде довольно таки тяжело, уже грабли эти пройдены, я через месяц забываю что я писал, а что нахожу нужное помечаю комментарием.
Если уж совсем все плохо, то лучше начать с нуля.

Answer (score 0):

Не вижу альтернативных вариантов, кроме как просмотреть участки кода и удалить ненужные. То есть сделать всё вручную.

Comment: Ну найти файлы, на которые нет ссылок -- это задача не сложная. А вот найти файлы, на которые ссылки в <script> есть, но код оттуда не вызывается -- несколько сложнее.